# can't file a folder in the directory | MacOS

Tags: python

I am using **deeppavlov** (https://deeppavlov.ai/) framework to work with NLP libraries. When i print `!python -c 'import deeppavlov;print(deeppavlov.__file__)'` to find a downloaded deeppavlov folder in my python directory i get `/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/deeppavlov/__init__.py`. However when i go to the exact that directory i can't find the file name *python3.7*. There is only *python3.8* and some other folder byt not *python3.7*. I tried *Spotlight search* as well as *finder>go to folder* but still can't find. Anybode has any idea whats going on here?

Comment: use `whereis python3.7` to get the location (considering your file structure i assumed that you are working with linux based OS)

Comment: thanks, but it doesn't give anything ( i tried it on terminal )

Comment: maybe it is installed on different name or not installed at all. But if you are using ubuntu (for example) than this will provide the path